# DB Csv export and Excel numbers formating

Tags: php, excel, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv, libreoffice

I am exporting a table from DB in csv format. I have numbers starting with 0, such as 04596 or 059438.
If I open this csv in LibreOffice or Excel,  the 0 will be thrown away and numbers are shown as 4596 and 59438.
I am exporting numbers as text, and if I open csv file in notepad++ the 0s are there, all of them.

Is there a workaround to make numbers visible as they are in file?

Comment: Do these numbers have quotes around them in the CSV file?

Comment: nope. just a plain text. I did such a trick as  `$temp['number'] = " ' " . $arr['number'] . " ' "`   , it shows numbers in Excel as '04569'   but  further manipulations with this file will be not easy

Comment: Perhaps try double quotes? `$temp = '"' . $arr['number'] . '"';`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do the trick either. Both  of them are shown in Excel or LibreOffice as "04569"  or '04569',  together with quots.

Comment: Do not **OPEN** the file. You must **IMPORT** the file into Excel and designate that column as being text at the time of import. You can use either Power Query (and Transform) or the legacy wizard for this.

Comment: I am opening it in LibreOffice Calc for now. The temporary solution from @JohnSUN works (first part till macros), but not sure that the client will agree to do it every time.

Comment: If you set up the import using Power Query, all your client should need to do when the content of the csv file  changes, would be to **Refresh** the query.

Answer (score 1):

When you open your CSV file in Calc manually, you see the text import filter settings window. Take your time to click OK, don't skip this step!

Select the columns that should not be recognized as numbers, but should remain text with a leading zero and specify their type as Text. Also set the correct types for the rest of the columns. You can specify Hide for columns that you do not need. Check the status of the rest of the parameters - code page, language, type of quotes for text fields, and so on.

[image: ImportCSV.png]

Just now click OK. Make sure the import went as you expected.

Now run this simple macro

```
Sub getMeCode
Dim oDoc As Variant
Dim aArgs As Variant
Dim sResult As String
Dim sTemp As String
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    aArgs = oDoc.getArgs()
    sTemp = getValArg(aArgs, "URL")
    sResult = "Dim sUrl As String, oDoc As Variant" + Chr(10) + "sUrl = convertToURL(""" + convertFromURL(sTemp) +""")" + Chr(10)
    sResult = sResult + "Dim OpenProp(1) as New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue" + Chr(10)
    sResult = sResult + "OpenProp(0).name=""FilterName""" + Chr(10)
    sResult = sResult + "OpenProp(1).name=""FilterOptions""" + Chr(10)
    sTemp = getValArg(aArgs, "FilterName")
    sResult = sResult + "OpenProp(0).value=""" + sTemp + """" + Chr(10)
    sTemp = getValArg(aArgs, "FilterOptions")
    sResult = sResult + "OpenProp(1).value=""" + sTemp + """" + Chr(10)
    sResult = sResult + "If Not FileExists(sUrl) Then Exit Sub" + Chr(10)
    sResult = sResult + "oDoc = stardesktop.LoadComponentFromURL(sUrl, ""_blank"",0, OpenProp())"
    MsgBox(sResult,0,"Select, Press Ctrl+C and Paste to macro")
End Sub
```

This macro uses the getValArg helper function, here is its text

```
Function getValArg(aArg As Variant, sNameArg As String) As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim tmp As Variant
    getValArg = ""
    For i = LBound(aArg) To UBound(aArg)
        tmp = aArg(i)
        If UCase(tmp.Name) = UCase(sNameArg) Then
            getValArg = tmp.Value
            Exit Function
        EndIf
    Next i
End Function
```

As a result, you will receive such a message.

[image: ImportCSVFilterOptions.png]

Pay attention to the underlined line. If you use just such a parameter for your files (regardless of the programming language that you use to open the file in Calc), then the result will be correct in most cases.

Comment: So, the first part of your comment did the trick! Now I can see all the zeros in this column, but I have to change the column type everytime I open the file. The second part with macros I can barerly understand. It has to be run in LibreOffice? I have to explain to the client, for example, that he has to run this macro prior opening the csv file ?

Comment: You can teach the client to use the setup window when opening files manually. In case the client is unwilling to learn, you can use the code that my macro outputs to create a custom extension for that stubborn client. The extension will be a macro, but the client does not need to know about it - he just will have a button on the toolbar, for example, "Open Your Price", which will always open your files in the required form. I don’t know your task, I don’t know how much you will train your client, I don’t know how much effort you are going to spend on it

Comment: Understood. That will be Plan B, and you are right, the client is really stubborn on this.

Answer (score 0):

convert it to string such as :
`echo "'".$number."'";`

Comment: it comes from db already as a string, I do not need to convert it